# can the language 0^n1^n be expressed as a regular grammar?

Tags: formal-languages

First off: I dont study computer science, just interested in formal languages.

I understand that this language is not regular because a finite state machine cannot count the number of a's preceeding the b (it would need a stack) and/or because you cannot express it as a regular expression, but isnt the following a regular grammmar defining the above language?

```
S -> 0S | 1S | epsilon
```

Or does this not count because of the epsilon?

Comment: regular expression is not equal to grammar - it would be possible ia grammar if you had something like S -> 0S1 | epsilon , but not with what you currently have, since there is nothing to prevent adding a non-matching number of 1's (or even that they are in the order 0 1).

Comment: *[...] isn't the following a regular grammmar defining the above language?* No. If you apply the productions S -> 0S and then S -> epsilon, you get the string "0", which is obviously not part of the language.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not programmers, but [CS stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks to all, I get it know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the context-free grammar that defines your language is

> S -> 0S1 | epsilon

You can actually build the tree, for example with the string 000111

> S -> 0S1 -> 00S11 -> 000S111 -> 000epsilon111 -> 000111

Be careful with the definitions of grammar and regular expression. The grammar you provided won't work, because it doesn't assure you to have an equal number of 0's and 1's. Test it for yourself, for example, with the string 00011, which isn't part of the language and yet it's recognized by your grammar.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrongfully thinking that my production rules can only be applied in order... which is totally wrong of course... I thought my grammar meant that I can only constrcut 01, 0011 and so on, so first 0 and then 1... And of course I didnt keep in mind that other wors can be constructed as well. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it (Please upvote my answer so I can reach 50 points haha).